# What can I do to protect my launcher from exit?

Tags: android, password-protection, android-launcher

I'm developing a home replacement application for kids. The user can't exit from the app (for example to open another application such as Settings) without a password.

What can I do to obtain this behavior?

I guess:

1. I should block the back button (done).
2. I should block the "recent apps" button (done but it's unstable)
3. I should block the access to the notification bar (is that possible? How?)
4. ...?

Answer (score 2):

I have spent the last 6 months developing this kind of application. The sad answer is, none of the above is fully possible. Android does not allow an application to meddle with things like notification bar, HOME Button or factory-reset resistance.

The only way to ensure you will be able to control all these things is to have a system signature, but it is only granted by the manufacturer for a selected phone model.

You can also try rooting the phone and meddling with the system config files directly, but it is rather dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the notification bar by using

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

With these the activity goes on fullscreen and should hide the notification bar.
However this works only for activity where you use it, so if you want to make it work for he entire app i suggeste you to put this inside the onCreate of a class that extends Activity and then make all of your activity extends this class.

Comment: It is enough to slide your finger downwards from the top of the screen to make the bar appear.